# What app creates files with random numbers as names on my SD card?

Tags: files

I have multiple files that appear seamingly randomly on my SD card with numbers as names such as :

- 40956591289
- 531333794524
- 19002876503010

The files are empty and can be created multiples times a day (with other names).

How do I find out which app creates them ?

Comment: Location of these files is directly in sdcard or in some folder inside sd card?

Comment: At the root of the SD card

Comment: It may be cache files. Just a guess